# How to fetch huge data from API to dropdownlist?

Tags: flutter

When I fetch the data from database it is giving an error , the error is not correct but it means that you are getting huge data .

here is the data that want to fecth it ;

[image]

here is the model of this data :

```
class DropdownListModel {
  int? id;
  String? name;

  DropdownListModel({this.id, this.name});

  DropdownListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['Id'];
    name = json['Name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['Id'] = id;
    data['Name'] = name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I tried to fetch it but cause of the huge data it gives renderflex error.

[image]

The code UI :

```
                          CustomDropDown(
                        width: 375,
                        focusNode: FocusNode(),
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        hintText: "Choose Airport",
                        items:
                            airports!.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((e) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: e.name,
                            child: Text(
                              e.name!,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            int index = airports!
                                .indexWhere((e) => e.name == value);
                            destinationAirportId =
                                int.parse(airports![index].id.toString());
                            debugPrint(
                                "destinationAirportId : " + destinationAirportId.toString());
                          });
                        },
                      )
```

Custom dropdown :

```
import 'package:hrsm/core/app_export.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomDropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomDropDown({
   super.key,
    this.alignment,
   this.width,
   this.margin,
   this.focusNode,
   this.icon,
  this.hintText,
  this.prefix,
  this.prefixConstraints,
  this.items,
   this.onChanged,
  });

 Alignment? alignment;

 double? width;

 EdgeInsetsGeometry? margin;

 FocusNode? focusNode;

Widget? icon;

String? hintText;

 Widget? prefix;

BoxConstraints? prefixConstraints;

List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>? items;

Function(dynamic)? onChanged;

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return _buildDropDownWidget();
}

_buildDropDownWidget() {
   return Container(
  width: width,
  margin: margin,
  child: DropdownButtonFormField(
    focusNode: focusNode,
    icon: icon,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: ColorConstant.black900,
      fontSize: getFontSize(
        14,
      ),
      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      height: 1.00,
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: hintText,
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: getFontSize(
          14.0,
        ),
        color: ColorConstant.black900,
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          getHorizontalSize(
            12.00,
          ),
        ),
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: ColorConstant.bluegray50,
          width: 1,
        ),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          getHorizontalSize(
            12.00,
          ),
        ),
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: ColorConstant.bluegray50,
          width: 1,
        ),
      ),
      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          getHorizontalSize(
            12.00,
          ),
        ),
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: ColorConstant.bluegray50,
          width: 1,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    items: items,
    onChanged: onChanged,
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Can you share the code of the UI?

Comment: I edited it , could you check it please sir ?

Comment: is it because of huge data or the length of text? try to a smaller fontsize or make a overflow to text.

Comment: Huge data sir because I change the data instead of include short data which length is 5 or 6 , it is not giving this error ,

Comment: Try to wrap your Text widget `FittedBox`

Comment: @SametDemirtop Is you data all same? Maybe one of your data's text is too long? Not in first 5 or 6 but at some point?

Comment: Can you add your text "overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis".

Comment: @aoitTenshi All data are same has ID and name and text long is a bit longer than other. and I added overflow but it is still same error occured

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I am sorry but same :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring that it's your widgets that are too big, causing a render overflow horizontally. If you're displaying this data directly in a `Text` widget, try instead doing this (order of widgets in your tree leading up to the `Text` widget):

`Row` -> `Expanded` -> `Text`

This may make the text wrap.

It's hard to answer without more details.

Comment: Sir when I change the data instead of include short data which length is 5 or 6 , it is not giving this error , I think the error occured for 1780 length of data

Comment: Maybe then wrap whatever you're using to display the data with inside a `SingleChildScrollView` widget? This will make it scrollable.

Comment: It is scrollable by dropdownlist proporties

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the size of the icon is too big. Try changing the size of the icon to a smaller number.

Comment: when ı delete the icon , still occured this error

Comment: Can you share the code for the `CustomDropDown` widget?

Comment: ı shared sir check it please

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

Your JSON String, id and List declaration

```
 String jsonString =
      '[ { "Id": 1787, "Name": "Zanesville"},{ "Id": 1788, "Name": "Carrasco International Airport"},{ "Id": 1789, "Name": "San Felipe"},{ "Id": 1790, "Name": "Valencia"},{ "Id": 1791, "Name": "Carvajal"},{ "Id": 1792, "Name": "Mansa"}]';
  String? id;
  List data = [];
```

API function:

```
 Future fetchJSONData() async {
    var jsonData = json.decode(jsonString);
    setState(() {
      data = jsonData;
    });
    return jsonData;
  }
```

Call your API fetchJSONData() inside initState()

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchJSONData();
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: InputDecorator(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: ButtonTheme(
                alignedDropdown: true,
                child: DropdownButton(
                  isDense: true,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  value: id,
                  hint: const Text(
                    "Choose Airport",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  items: data.map((list) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text(
                        list['Name'],
                        overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                      ),
                      value: list['Id'].toString(),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      id = value as String;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Result Screen->

1-> [image: Initial Dropdown]

2- >[image: Dropdown Data]

3->[image: Selected Value]